# Intentionally assisting a suicidal person

Tags: texas, murder, suicide

Bob posts on an anonymous online board that he wants to kill himself.

Alice reads his post. She visits Bob's home and hands him a gun. However, Alice warns Bob not to use the gun to kill himself. He does it anyway.

Is Alice guilty for Bob's death?

Comment: In which country/state?

Comment: Does it make a difference? Let's say Texas.

Comment: Why is Alice giving him a gun and telling him not to use it? What is she trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NicholasMarshall it absolutely matters. Laws are different in different states and countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intent matters here, but yes. Alice could be considered guilty of either Second-Degree Murder or Manslaughter, though the latter is far more likely.

Texas has no laws condoning assisted suicide that could absolve Alice.

Second-degree murder requires the following:

- The defendant intentionally and knowingly caused the death of another person
- The defendant intended to cause serious bodily injury and committed an act that was clearly dangerous to human life and this act caused the death of an individual

This is tenuous, but it could be argued this way if Alice intended to cause Bob's death. It certainly meets the second criteria: shooting oneself constitutes serious harm and giving a firearm to someone who has stated an intent to kill themself is reckless.

It's more likely that Alice would be charged with manslaughter. The only definition is:

- A person commits an offense if he recklessly causes the death of an
  individual.

As discussed above, giving someone who has announced an intent to kill themself a loaded gun is reckless. Alice's actions resulted in Bob's death.